# Why embedded vaadin 14 components don't show up on the XHTML page?

Tags: wildfly, facelets, vaadin14, pnpm

I'm developing a demo project with Vaadin 14.2 along with facelets and wildfly 18.
Using `pnpm` enabled in the `pom.xml`.

I'm tried to embed one of my Vaadin view in the facelets page as mentioned in the doc on Vaadin website as below.

**Why embedded component don't show up on the facelets page?**

I tried both debug and production mode.

Error on debug mode is as below while navigating to the JSF page:

```
ERROR [dev-webpack] (webpack) ERROR in ../target/frontend/generated-flow-imports.js
ERROR [dev-webpack] (webpack) Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@vaadin/flow-frontend/' in 'C:\Development\workspace\soft\fering-web\target\frontend'
ERROR [dev-webpack] (webpack)  @ ../target/frontend/generated-flow-imports.js 82:0-32
```

Error on production mode is as below while navigating to the facelets page:

```
14:53:33,277 ERROR [com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.FrontendUtils] (default task-4) Cannot get the 'stats.json' from the classpath 'META-INF/VAADIN/config/stats.json'
14:53:33,282 ERROR [com.vaadin.flow.server.DefaultErrorHandler] (default task-4) : com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapException: Unable to read webpack stats file.
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The stats file from webpack (stats.json) was not found.
The application is running in production mode.Verify that build-frontend task has executed successfully and that stats.json is on the classpath.Or switch application to development mode.
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler$BootstrapPageBuilder.appendNpmBundle(BootstrapHandler.java:923)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler$BootstrapPageBuilder.setupFrameworkLibraries(BootstrapHandler.java:889)
    ... 59 more

14:53:33,287 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-4) UT005023: Exception handling request to /fering/vaadin/web-component/web-component-bootstrap.js: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceException: com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapException: Unable to read webpack stats file.
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:249)
    at com.vaadin.cdi.CdiVaadinServlet.service(CdiVaadinServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
```

**Facelets xhtml page**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<f:view contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<ui:include src="/include/queryHeader.xhtml"/>
<h:head>
    <h:outputScript name="jquery/jquery.js" library="primefaces"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vaadin/VAADIN/build/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"  ></script>
    <script type="module" src="vaadin/web-component/first-view.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        first-view {
            width: 100%;
        }
        body {
            margin: 8px;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <hr/>
    <first-view></first-view>

</h:body>

</html>
```

**Vaadin embedded component**

```
@Tag("first-view")
@PreserveOnRefresh
public class FirstViewExporter  extends WebComponentExporter<FirstView> {
    public FirstViewExporter() {
        super("first-view");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configureInstance(WebComponent<FirstView> webComponent, FirstView firstView) {

    }
}
```

**pom.xml production profile**

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <pnpmEnable>true</pnpmEnable>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Comment: There are no jsf components here, just facelets tags. I updated your title, tag and text

Comment: Using Openjdk instead of Amazon Coretto fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the production mode: please make sure that the `META-INF/VAADIN/config/stats.json` resource is somewhere in your EAR/WAR/JAR. It should have been produced by the Vaadin Maven Plugin, the `build-frontend` goal - please verify from Maven stdout that the goal has been run. There is also a bit of information here: https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17763152/vaadin-14-npm-mode-production-profile ; also Vaadin might have trouble discovering classpath files in skinny EARs.

It could also be that there is an issue with this specific configuration. In such case just let us know, either on forums or at https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues

Regarding the development mode: the `target\frontend` folder should no longer be needed with Vaadin 14.2. It could be that you have migrated from Vaadin 14.1 but the javascript files haven't been updated. Please try to clean the Vaadin files: namely, delete `node_modules`, `pnpm-lock.yaml`, `package.json`, `pnpmfile.js`, `webpack.generated.js` and try the development mode once more.

**Feedback on your reply:**

I have attached a screenshot with more detail of project structuers and also `web.xml`

From stdout I can see that the `build-frontend` goal has been executed.

As you can see on the screenshot below, `stats.json` is not produced by `vaadin maven plugin` in none of `META_INF` directory.
[image]

Comment: As to be sure if problem is from vaadin 
I have checked out this example(https://labs.vaadin.com/vaadin-jsf/index.xhtml) and changed it to vaadin 14.2.1 and pnpm enabled using wildfly 20 final.
When I run it, I see Vaadin-maven-plugin does not create stats.json file.

Comment: Could you please try out this fork of the example project? https://github.com/mvysny/vaadin-jsf-embedding . When I build it with `mvn -C clean package -Pproduction`, the resulting WAR archive correctly contains the `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/VAADIN/config/stats.json`.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I did use exact configuration as yours in my project but strange things is that if I run project via IntelliJ run configuration, it uses Vaadin plug-in 14.2.0 to prepare-frontend and  build-frontend instead of Vaadin 14.2.2 while Vaadin 14.2.2 is configured in my pom.xml. I think this is the cause of problem and I still don't know why this happens. The only different between my project and yours is that I use also vaadin-cdi in the pom.xml and CdiVaadinServlet in web.xml